# How can I use javafx to draw a asterisk graph

Tags: javafx

I need to use javafx or javafx scene builder to draw a asterisk graph like this:

[image]

I want to ask, is there any easier method, except I figure out every point position?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think there is an easier solution.

Comment: I suppose you can just figure out the coordinates of the end points of two adjacent lines. Then create five copies of those lines, each rotated by 72*i degrees around the center of the star. I'm not sure that's actually easier...